# Disable li anchors mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I've got a beautiful responsive gallery up and running, with the prettyPhoto plugin for easier viewing of the images. This of course works brilliantly on desktop/laptop computers, but is absolutely horrible on mobile. (longer load time, images that don't fit the screen because of predetermined CSS etc.)

I could just tell the browser not to load the prettyPhoto.js on mobile, but then the thumbnail anchors would still link to the full size images. (Which I don't want! The thumbnails are big enough for mobile, no need for the full size image.)

There must be some kind of jQuery or JavaScript solution for this. I am not sure what the best approach to take is and was hoping someone could provide some insight to a solution to this issue.

HTML:

```
<ul id="portfolio">
  <section id="photos">
    <li class="all"> <a href="fullsize.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[all]"> <img src="thumb.jpg"> </a> </li>
    <li class="all"> <a href="fullsize.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[all]"> <img src="thumb.jpg"> </a> </li>
    <li class="all"> <a href="fullsize.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[all]"> <img src="thumb.jpg"> </a> </li>
    <li class="all"> <a href="fullsize.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[all]"> <img src="thumb.jpg"> </a> </li>
  </section>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

What I've got so far is:

```
<script>
if ( $(window).width() < 767) {
   $('#portfolio img').unwrap();
)};
</script>
```

Which doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `.unwrap()` jquery method:

http://jsfiddle.net/fm9Un/1/

```
$(function(){ //DOM ready
    if($(window).width() < 767)
         $('#portfolio img').unwrap();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. So how do I trigger this .unwrap() for let's say.. a screen with max-width: 767px

Comment: see updated answer. You could eventually look at window onresize event but this snippet is answering basically your question

Comment: Fantastic, that did the trick. I'll add a window.onresize and it'll be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!